# Moving Wordpress To New Host - Importing Database Error #1062

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, import

I am moving a wordpress website to a new domain & hosting and I am having problems with this. I have backed up the whole site, imported it via ftp to the new domain and installed wordpress.

However when I try to import my old database to the new site I get this error:

```
    Error

    SQL query:

    -- -- Dumping data for table `wp_contact_form_7` -- INSERT INTO `wp_contact_form_7` (`cf7_unit_id`, `title`, `form`, `mail`, `mail_2`, `messages`, `additional_settings`) VALUES (1, 'Contact form 1', '

    Your Name (required)
    \r\n [text* your-name 35/100]
    \r\n


    \r\n

    Your Email (required)
    \r\n [email* your-email 35/100]
    \r\n
    \r\n

    Your Message
    \r\n [textarea your-message 30/5]
    \r\n\r\n

    [submit "Send"]
    ', 'a:7:{s:7:"subject";s:32:"Nixonsolicitors.com Contact Form";s:6:"sender";s:26:"[your-name] <[your-email]>";s:4:"body";s:194:"From: [your-name] <[your-email]>\r\nSubject: Nixonsolicitors.com Contact Form\r\n\r\nMessage Body:\r\n[your-message]\r\n\r\n\r\n--\r\nThis mail is sent via contact form on Nixon & Co http://nixonsolicitors.com/nixon";s:9:"recipient";s:14:"hugh@vbs4u.com";s:18:"additional_headers";s:0:"";s:11:"attachments";s:0:"";s:8:"use_html";s:0:"";}', 'a:8:{s:6:"active";s:0:"";s:7:"subject";s:14:"[your-subject]";s:6:"[...]

    MySQL said: Documentation
    #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 1
```

How can I sort this problem?

Thanks,

Hugh

Answer (score 2):

Export your DB correctly with phpmyadmin: http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database#Using_phpMyAdmin

And see [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Be sure and change your URLs the right way: [How to Move WordPress Blog to New Domain or Location  »  My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/10/01/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/)

MySQL versions the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
Duplicate entry '1' for key 1
```

This means that a record with that key already exists. More than likely your import didn't finish the first time and is now failing to insert upon subsequent imports. Make sure you are importing to a fresh database - i.e. drop all your existing WP tables first.

I'd also suggest doing a WordPress import/export from the WordPress Administration. This will keep you from having to worry about any environment specific database changes between your webhost and just move the WordPress data.